# Increment variable lisp in local function

Tags: lisp, global-variables, common-lisp

How can i increment a variable in a local function and the change to persist ?

```
(defun inc(x) (+ x 1))

(setq a 1)
```

I want this (inc a) to change the value of a to 2

I searched this problem , and i find something with setf but i couldn't resolve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your exact problem, this may be answered in [Variable references in lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1249991/1281433), which discusses the particular issues of lexical scope that you may be encountering.  It even uses the same example of incrementing the value of a variable, so it's particularly relevant.

However, if you're just looking for how to increment a value, then you may be interested in the  standard function [**1+**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_1pl_1_.htm), where **(1+ x)** is equivalent to **(+ x 1)**, and the macro [**incf**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_incf_.htm) for incrementing the value of a place by **1**.

```
(let ((a 1))      (let ((a 1))
  (1+ a))           (incf a)
                    a)
;=> 2             ;=> 2
```

However, depending on exactly what you're trying to do, these might not work for you (and the possible duplicate is more appropriate).  If you're trying to call a function with the *value* of a variable, and then have the body of the function effect a change in the binding of the variable, then you can't do it.  That is, there is no *function* that can make this work:

```
(let ((a 1))
  (foo a)
  a)
;=> 2
```

The function **foo** is called with the *value* of the variable **a**, which is the number **1**; it doesn't have any access to the *variable*, so it can't bind the *variable* to a new value.  However, a *macro* can work with the *unevaluated* forms it is called with, so you can have the sort of side effects that you may be looking for.  E.g.:

```
(let ((a 1))
  (incf a)
  a)
;=> 2
```

However, as explained above, you can't do:

```
(defun my-incf (x)
  (incf x))         ; modifies the binding of x

(let ((a 1))
  (my-incf a)
  a)
;=> 2
```

because the call to **incf** changes the *binding* of **x**, which is a variable that is local to **my-incf**.