# Lisp / parameter-passing

Tags: lisp, parameter-passing, common-lisp

In order to solve some issue I am having while using Common Lisp, I browsed the net and found this:
[Variable references in lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249991/variable-references-in-lisp)
which is very related to my problem.

Reading this part:

***Think functional!***
..................
So, to do what you want, the code needs a) be in the scope or b) have access to functions that are in the scope.

I am trying to make sense of it, but things are not clear.

First I am not sure what a) and b) refer to in the last sentence.

Second how do I practically make use of the two chunks of code provided to get the desired result?

Thanks in advance for any relevant tip.

Comment: What is the 'desired result'?  In fact, what question are you asking?

Comment: Basically, you can only set variables to which you have access, either directly (the scope) or indirectly, by calling a closure which closes over a set of variables (or mutating a field, an array). Read http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/variables.html

Answer (score 1):

I still can't quite work out what question you are asking, but I think you want to know how you can modify bindings in a scope within functions which can't see the bindings.  So here is an answer to that question.

The first thing to understand is that scope in modern programming languages is terribly simple: if you can see a binding (an association between a name and a value) then you have access to it, and if it's mutable you can mutate it.  Pre-modern programming languages have all sorts of arcane rules which constrain this based on ease of implementation on tiny computers a long time ago (we are all cursed by the legacy of the PDP-11), but modern ones sweep all this away.  Common Lisp is mostly a modern programming language in this sense.

So what you need to do is to capture a binding somehow, and then pass that captured binding into whatever functions you want to call, where it can be accessed or mutated.  The way you capture a binding is with a function.

So, here is a simple example of how to do this in CL:

```
(defun foo (orig new)
  (let ((x orig))
    (bar (lambda (&optional (value nil valuep))
           (if valuep
               (setf x value)
             x))
         new)
    x))

(defun bar (c new)
  (format t "~&initially ~S~%" (funcall c))
  (funcall c new)
  (format t "~&then ~S~%" (funcall c)))
```

In this code the function created by the first argument to `bar` has access to the binding of `x`, and is so written so that calling it with no arguments will return the value of the binding, while calling it with an argument will set the value.  Here is that in action:

```
CL-USER 5 > (foo 1 2)
initially 1
then 2
2
```

So you can see this works: the binding of `x` is modified by calls to the function which captured it.

But this is syntactically clunky: it would be nice if we could avoid all these explicit `funcall`s and `lambda`s (we could avoid the former in a Lisp-1, but it's still not really nice).  So here some code which does that (explanation of it below):

```
(defmacro capture (binding)
  "Capture a binding"
  (let ((value (make-symbol "VALUE"))
        (valuep (make-symbol "VALUEP")))
    `(lambda (&optional (,value nil ,valuep))
       (if ,valuep
           (setf ,binding ,value)
         ,binding))))

(defun captured (c &optional (value nil valuep))
  "Return the value of a captured binding, or set it"
  (if valuep
      (funcall c value)
    (funcall c)))

(defsetf captured captured)
```

OK, so the macro `capture` is just syntactic sugar which creates a function identical to the one in the original code.  It has to be a macro because the function needs to be created in the scope of the binding it is capturing.

`captured` is then a trivial function which just calls the function created by `capture` in a suitable way: so rather than saying `(funcall c)` we can say `(captured c)`.

Finally the `defsetf` form teaches `setf` how to set captured bindings, so `(setf (captured x) y)` will work.

And here are reimplementations of the above `foo` and `bar` functions which use this:

```
(defun foo (orig new)
  (let ((x orig))
    (bar (capture x) new)
    x))

(defun bar (c new)
  (format t "~&initially ~S~%" (captured c))
  (setf (captured c) new)
  (format t "~&then ~S~%" (captured c)))
```

I think it's obvious that this is nicer to read than all the explicit `funcall`s and `lambda`s above.  And it works the same way:

```
CL-USER 6 > (foo 1 2)
initially 1
then 2
2
```

---

Incidentally, you can capture expresssions, not just variable bindings, of course, so long as `setf` knows what to do with them (so long as they are what it calls 'places'):

```
(defun fish (l)
  (bone (capture (car l)))
  l)

(defun bone (c)
  (setf (captured c) 'bone))
```

And now

```
CL-USER 13 > (fish (list 1 2))
(bone 2)
```