# Elisp variable bind to itself

Tags: emacs, elisp, lexical-scope

I have elisp code like this:

```
(setq a nil)
(defun testa (a) (add-to-list a "ABCD"))
(testa 'a)
```

What I want is to make `a` list `("ABCD")` but since the argument name of the function `testa` is the same as variable `a`, the local binding of `a` in the function is itself, which doesn't bind the value outside of function.

My question is: Is it the feature of elisp that I can't work around if I don't rename the variable outside or is there any neat solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the intended behavior in elisp.  For more information on variable scoping with elisp, [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dynamic-Binding.html) has a thorough explanation.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249991/variable-references-in-lisp) also does a good job of explaining scoping.

It is not possible to pass a reference to a variable.  It is however possible to pass a function that returns or modifies a globally (or dynamically) scoped variable.  It is also possible to have a function that modifies an already known variable.

Edit: Added more detail.

Comment: This does not answer the question - it does not explain the behavior the OP is wondering about. Please incorporate some relevant parts of the explanation you link to. Otherwise this is essentially a link-only answer and risks being deleted.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I need to define the function using lexical binding which works.